# ADO.NET Entity Framework: QUERY n-n relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have four tables:

- Client with PK **ClientID**.
- Destination with PK **DestinationID**.
- Language with PK **LanguageID**.
- DestinationDetail with PK **DestinationID**.
- RL-Client-Destination with PKs **ClientID** and **DestinationID**.

The Client may have zero or n Destinations. A destination has n DestinationDetails, each of these DestinationDetail has a language.

Ok. I need to retrieve all of DestinationDetails for a given client and a given language.

I wrote this (I don't kown if it works), but maybe there is a better way:

```
    ObjectQuery clientQuery =
       guiaContext.Client.Where("it.email = @email",
           new ObjectParameter("email", "xxx@example.com"));

    Client client = clientQuery.First();

    client.Destination.Load();
    EntityCollection destinations = client.Destination;

    ObjectQuery languageQuery =
       guiaContext.Language.Where("it.ds_language = @languageDS",
         new ObjectParameter("languageDS", "en-US"));
    Language language = languageQuery.First();

    foreach (Destination dest in destinations)
    {
        dest.DestinationDetail.Load();
        EntityCollection details = dest.DestinationDetail;
        foreach (DestinationDetail detail in details)
        {
           detail.Language = language;
           Console.WriteLine("Destination: " + detail.ds_destinationName);
        }
     }
```

I'm learning ADO.NET Entity Framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
var db = new PracticeEntities();
var destinations = db.DestinationDetails.
          Where(dd => dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
          dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email == "abc@yahoo.com"));
```

Thank you!